# Why flask does not return result?

Tags: python, flask, deployment, pytorch, torchvision

I am new to deep learning and flask deployment and I am trying to deploy a pytorch model(resnet34) with flask. When I try to upload an image to check the predictions, it does not show any predictions. It does not show any errors in my code.

The HTML page where I upload images.

```
<form method ='post' enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type="file" name="file" >
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
```

The html page where I want to see the predictions.

```
<body>
    <h2>Prediction</h2>
    <p>Currency Name: {{ currency }}</p>
</body>
```

App.py for flask

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, jsonify
from commons import get_tensor
from inference import get_currency_name
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello_world():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', value='hi')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            file = request.files['file']
            image = file.read()
            print(request.files)
            if 'file' not in request.files:
                print('file not uploaded')
                return
            file = request.files['file']
            image = file.read()
            currency_name = get_currency_name(image_bytes=image)
            category, currency_name = get_currency_name(image_bytes=image)
            get_currency_name(image_bytes=image)
            tensor = get_tensor(image_bytes=image)
            print(get_tensor(image_bytes=image))
            print(currency_name)
            return render_template('result.html', currency=currency_name, category=category)
            #return jsonify({'category': category, 'currency_name': currency_name})
        
        except:
            
            return render_template('result.html')


        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

commons.py code

```
import io

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision import models, transforms
from PIL import Image

def get_model():
    checkpoint_path = 'checkpoint.pth'
    model = models.resnet34(pretrained=True)
    model.classifier = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(512, 6))
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(
        checkpoint_path, map_location='cpu'), strict=False)
    model.eval()
    print("model loaded!!")
    return model

def get_tensor(image_bytes):
    my_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224),
                                        transforms.ToTensor(),
                                        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 
                                                                std=[0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
                                        ])
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
    return my_transforms(image).unsqueeze(0)
```

code for inference.py

```
import torch
from commons import get_model, get_tensor

class_names = ['Rs. 20', 'Rs. 100', 'Rs. 500', 'Rs. 10', 'fake 100', 'Fake 500']
model = get_model()
def get_currency_name(image_bytes):
    tensor = get_tensor(image_bytes)
    outputs = model(tensor)
    _, preds = outputs.max(2)
    category = preds.item()
    currency_name = class_names[category]

    return currency_name
```

When I select an image and submit, it does not return any result to result.html and does not show any errors either.
What could have possibly gone wrong??

Comment: GET works but POST does not?  What is output are you getting (i.e. from your print statements) on console?  What output is sent to browser (header, body)?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so if we are debugging POST start by bisecting the code till you have something that works.  You seem to assign file and image twice so start by just removing that.

Comment: `if 'file' not in request.files:` If that is the case you return None and you get this error.

Comment: I found the problem lies in this line while debugging
            tensor = get_tensor(image_bytes=image)

Comment: The image is not being converted to tensors